# Prestashop search module doesnt work after adding www. to my shopdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, smarty, prestashop

Since I added www. before my shop domain my search module doesn’t work anymore. It seems that the url request stays in a loop. All other pages works fine with the www. addition.

The search page appear well without the rewrite and the the url is like this:

http://myshop.com/index.php?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&submit_search.x=0&submit_search.y=0&search_query=t

When I activate rewriting with www. the url occurrence is like this:

http://www.myshop.com/search?orderby=position&orderway=desc&submit_search_x=0&submit_search_y=0&search_query=t

In the last url is index.php?controller= missing and after search there is a question mark. The browser says he can‘t display the page because the url rewriting stays in a loop. How can I solve this?

This is the .htaccess generated by Prestashop:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
```